# How to measure the heart rate for 1 minute, every x minutes, no matter the state of iOS and Watch apps are in?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, heartbeat

I'm working on a Watch App that requires measuring the heart rate continuously for 1 minute, every x minutes (30 minimum). The data needs to be sent to the phone and, from there, to a remote Web Service.

This should work no matter what the state both the iOS and WatchOs apps are in:

- Active
- Background
- Closed

I tried using HKWorkoutSession but the Watch App keeps opening when the heart rate starts being measured(when the minute starts). I need everything to be done without alerting the user (There is a long Terms Page that he must agree prior to using the app).

I'm using the code fragments below on the watch:

```swift
do {
    self.workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: self.healthStore, 
                                               configuration: self.workoutConfiguration)
    self.workoutSession?.delegate = self
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to create a workout session object")
}
self.workoutSession?.startActivity(with: Date())
```

I use `self.workoutSession?.stopActivity(with: Date())` after 1 to stop the activity

Comment: This library from Thomas might have a solution. https://github.com/thomaspaulmann/HeartControl